# MvvmCross ViewModel null when Android Dev option Don't keep activities is active

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross 3.1.1 from Nuget packages.

I was testing my app for problems in low memory environments by enabling the "Don't keep activities" option in Android developer options.

I was expecting to see issues where I hadn't saved/reloaded my state, but I wasn't expecting to see that the ModelView for my View was null. Doesn't MvvmCross handle the rehydration of the ModelView class?

I've read the documentation at: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle - However I don't see any mention of restoring the ModelView myself, only the data contained within.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the code where it's null? Mvx will create a new vm in base.oncreate for a reinflated activity

Comment: I've done some more testing with this and I think it's because I've got a ViewModel as part of another ViewModel and I initialize the ViewModel as part of an Init with Params call. So basically I need to re-init the ViewModel again after the container ViewModel is restored.